# linux + how to know the time details from df command

Tags: linux, netapp, disk-volume, df

is it possible to know when partition was mounted from  storage volume?

for example latly we know about that netapp19:/volume/orsdcp_nfs was mounted on /oraT

but how to know when? ( regarding that we not have info from history command )

```
 14:28:01 root@serverFF100:/ # df -h
  Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/rootvg-slash             60M  431M  168M  73% /
 tmpfs                                5.G  8.0K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
 /dev/mapper/opt                      92M  445M  496M  48% /opt
 /dev/mapper/hds                      5G  2.0G  2.8G  42% /opt/hds
 /dev/mapper/usr                      1.G  996M  320M  76% /usr
 /dev/mapper/var                      3G  853M  2.0G  30% /var
 /dev/mapper/home                     28M   40M  196M  17% /home
 /dev/sdb1                            16M   69M   78M  47% /boot
 tmpfs                                3.2G   52K  3.0G   1% /tmp
 netapp10:/volume/eedfede/ildgdb01       1G   50G   65G  44% /erfa
 netapp10:/volume/lwdefe_nfs             77G  713G   54G  94%       /ora/data/lgrerrd
 netapp10:/volume/sdfdcv_nfs             49G   41G  360G  11%   /ora/data/sddfed
 netapp19:/volume/orsdcp_nfs             89G   82G  778G  10% /oraT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on remote storage server, if it has some logs about nfs accesses. `df` command will show you only disk usage stats, nothing more. If you don't have any logs, you can prepare cronjob for every 5 minutes, which will run `mount` and compare result with expected mounts. Maybe something will be in system logs, but I think it will not.

Basically you cannot detect when some target has been mounted ex-post.